# How to subset raster image using gdal?

Tags: raster, gdal, c++

I have read pixel values of an raster image using GDAL libraries in visual studio 2010(vc++).

Now I have to crop the image (subset) according to the grid given in shape file.

I have got a code for cropping image on internet as given below, but its having some error in it.
Please review it and help .

```
GDALDataset* crop(GDALDataset* poDS, int xoff, int yoff, int xsize, int ysize)
{
        VRTDataset *poVDS = (VRTDataset*)VRTCreate(xsize, ysize);

        // Copy dataset info
        const char* pszProjection = poDS->GetProjectionRef();
        if (pszProjection != NULL && strlen(pszProjection) > 0)
                poVDS->SetProjection(pszProjection);

        double adfGeoTransform[6];
        if (poDS->GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform) == CE_None)
        {
                 // Adapt the geotransform matrix to the subarea
                    adfGeoTransform[0] += xoff * adfGeoTransform[1]
                        + yoff * adfGeoTransform[2];
                adfGeoTransform[3] += xoff * adfGeoTransform[4]
                        + yoff * adfGeoTransform[5];

                poVDS->SetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);
        }

        poVDS->SetMetadata(poDS->GetMetadata());

        // Here I also copy metadata from my own domain
        char **papszMD;
         papszMD = poDS->GetMetadata(MD_DOMAIN_MSAT);
               if (papszMD != NULL)
                 poVDS->SetMetadata(papszMD, MD_DOMAIN_MSAT);

         for (int i = 0; i < poDS->GetRasterCount(); ++i)
         {
                 GDALRasterBand* poSrcBand = poDS->GetRasterBand(i + 1);
                 GDALDataType eBandType = poSrcBand->GetRasterDataType();
                 poVDS->AddBand(eBandType, NULL);
                 VRTSourcedRasterBand* poVRTBand = (VRTSourcedRasterBand*)poVDS- >GetRasterBand(i + 1);
                 poVRTBand->AddSimpleSource(poSrcBand,
                                 xoff, yoff,
                                 xsize, ysize,
                                 0, 0, xsize, ysize);
                 poVRTBand->CopyCommonInfoFrom(poSrcBand);

                 // Again, I copy my own metadata
                 papszMD = poSrcBand->GetMetadata(MD_DOMAIN_MSAT);
                 if (papszMD != NULL)
                         poVRTBand->SetMetadata(papszMD, MD_DOMAIN_MSAT);
         } 

         return poVDS;
 }
```

Comment: please don't post twice in stack exchange sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213205/how-to-subset-raster-image-using-gdal

Answer (score 12):

Unprojected:

`gdal_translate -srcwin xstart ystart xstop ystop input.raster output.raster`

Projected:

`gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry input.raster output.raster`

If you are using gdal on your system, gdal_translate is installed.

Comment: Hello jay laura: thank you for the reply but the lines you have suggested works for python i guess. i only uses c++ code. So i dont think gdal_translate work in c++ coding .

Comment: @hardik, `gdal_translate` is written in C++ and operates independently of the gdal python bindings, here's the code: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdal_translate.cpp. It's part of the core utility set and a compiled binary is generally installed by default (unless you're not installing and only building from source).

Comment: The unprojected command seems inconsistent with the documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html, which says `-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "projected" and "unprojected".  My raster has a projection, but I don't want to reproject it — which form is correct?

Comment: @colllin "projected" means you can specify the coordinates using the coordinate format of the projection (e.g. for example if using EPSG:4326 you can provide 90/180 lat/lon coordinates) and "unprojected" means you specify coordinates as x/y pixel values of the raster. For projected, you can specify the SRS using -projwin_srs. It does not actually reproject anything in the output.

Answer (score 4):

See the [GDALRasterBand Class](https://gdal.org/api/gdalrasterband_cpp.html). Carefully using the `nXOff` and `nXSize` (etc.) parameters of [GDALRasterBand::RasterIO](https://gdal.org/api/gdalrasterband_cpp.html#_CPPv4N14GDALRasterBand8RasterIOE10GDALRWFlagiiiiPvii12GDALDataType8GSpacing8GSpacingP20GDALRasterIOExtraArg) will read a "cropped" part of the raster.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Mike. I have solved the problem of cropping the image using VC++ with gdal libraries. I have created VRTDataset of my desired size of raster to be cropped and then save it using CreateCopy().