# Cut raster images according to unique value raster used as mask, and save obtained images according to mask's value

Tags: qgis, raster, sentinel-2

I have seven Sentinel-2 images of a region opened as raster files. I have a .tif file with 100x100m squares covering the whole region (so all 7 images are covered by this mask). Each square has one label between 0 and 17.

I would like to clip my satellite images according to the squares, and store each smaller image in .jpg2 format in different folders numbered from 0 to 17 according to the label of the square on the mask.

Basically, [this problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82313/how-to-cut-multiple-neighboring-raster-images), except I want to cut in more pieces and those pieces must be labeled according to the mask raster. In QGIS, I have projected all my files to the same projection, then clipped according to my mask raster, but then I don't know what to do.

My final result should be 30,000 images in .jpg2, stored in 17 different folders depending on their label.

How can I get that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you have 'labels on top?'

Comment: Is it clearer after this edit? Labels on top just mean that I need to keep the labels on my final images (they need to end up in the right folder after they're cut up).

Comment: You have a complicated geoprocessing task that can be handled in many different ways.  Each step could (and should) be a its own GIS SE question.  Are you hoping to do this in one step, using the graphical modeler, or with something like Python?  The first step would be to sort out how to split a single image.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166909/splitting-raster-in-qgis-without-cliper

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to automate the whole process as I will be needing to do it multiple times (I have as of now 7 different masks and may get more to test later). A Python script would be the most optimized way I think as Qgis tends to be a bit slow.

Comment: This link will get you started with GDAL translate to crop an image based on known extents.  This example is using GDAL shell commands but you can always run shell commads in Python using the os module.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45509/how-to-subset-raster-image-using-gdal  and https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-python/